# Error running sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-78-generic x86_64) on a headless server. I get an issue with `plexmediaserver` each time I run package updates. Here is the output from the terminal.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up plexmediaserver (1.5.6.3790-4613ce077) ...
OK
Failed to execute operation: File exists
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:  plexmediaserver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I resolve this?

**Update:**

Results of running sudo dpkg --configure -a

```
Setting up plexmediaserver (1.5.6.3790-4613ce077) ...  
OK  
Failed to execute operation: File exists  
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation  script returned error exit status 1  
Errors were encountered while processing:  plexmediaserver
```

Results of running sudo apt install -f:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Setting up plexmediaserver (1.5.6.3790-4613ce077) ... 
OK 
Failed to execute operation: File exists
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--configure): 
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing:  
plexmediaserver 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Results of running sudo apt install --reinstall plexmediaserver:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
Reinstallation of plexmediaserver is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Setting up plexmediaserver (1.5.6.3790-4613ce077)... 
OK 
Failed to execute operation: File exists 
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--configure):  
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plexmediaserver 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As you can see I am getting pretty much the same error messages each time.

I used Atomic Toolkit to install plexmedia server. 
 (https://github.com/htpcBeginner/AtoMiC-ToolKit)

Comment: Please add the output of this commands to your question with **code tag** : `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo apt install --reinstall plexmediaserver` . and descript that how did you install `plexmediaserver` and with which repository ?